# Custom translation for Type in Stage Opportunity

Tags: opportunity, translation, standard-field

Is that possible to translate this type of stage

[image]

Open and closed

Comment: did you check if it is showing in any place for end user or it is only a configuration info? I believe it is a config and it is now showing to the end user. There is a field in Opportunity to say if it is Open or Close, Win or Lost.

Comment: It is shown in the reports, as a filter and i couldnt remove it, It is not very relevant either, but the translation into Spanish is wrong and it is a bit strange